# whats timer available in winRT similar to system.threading.timer and ...change() method

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I need same functionality in winRT that system.threading.timer provides. I found     ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(TimerElapsedHandler, TimeSpan, TimerDestroyedHandler) method in  Windows.System.Threading; but unable to perform below functionality.

Actually, I have to write following code in winRT as I am unable to perform;

```
system.threading.timer timer;
timer = new Timer(CleanupThreadCallback, null, cleanupFrequenceMS, cleanupFrequenceMS)
and
timer.change(_cleanupFrequency, _cleanupFrequency);
```

Comment: Did you check [`DispatcherTimer `](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer) ?

Comment: Actually, DispatcherTimer links to Xaml UI but I am just converting existing .Net library to winRT. I wrote the code above that is written in library; it also uses a callback and timer.change(, ) method
I just want to fulfil this need.
Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Not sure if that helps, but I wrote a timer a while back that you can get [here](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Tools/BackgroundTimer.cs). Someone also wrote a wrapper on top of `DispatcherTimer` that makes its API surface compatible with `ThreadPoolTimer` [here](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/761).

Comment: @FilipSkakun The link to the BackgroundTimer.cs you made seems broken..is it still available or was it removed ?

Comment: It did move here: https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Tools/BackgroundTimer.cs